# JSONSchema to TypeScript - Defining a record of strings to strings

Tags: json, typescript, jsonschema

I'm using json-schema-to-typescript and would like to specify an array of strings.

Currently, I have the following:

```
      "type": "object",
      "description": "...",
      "additionalProperties": true,
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
```

When converted to TS, it returns `[k: string]: unknown;`

I'd like for it to return `[k: string]: string;` instead.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`items` is an array keyword, but you have specified `"type": "object"`. Have you tried changing that to `"type": "array"` and removing `additionalProperties`?

Comment: I did, but it returns `string[]`, instead of what I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

I did it by removing the `items` property and changing to `"additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }`

Comment: If you're expecting objects, then the "items" keyword shouldn't be there, as that applies only to arrays.